# Centos 6.7 boot hangs on progress bar but ssh fine

Tags: linux, centos, centos-6

I have just upgraded my kernel to:

```
2.6.32-642.6.2.el6.x86_64 #1 SMP Wed Oct 26 06:52:09 UTC 2016
```

on my

```
CentOS release 6.7 (Final)
```

and rebooted my system (Dell R820). The boot progress bar completes but does not drop to the terminal. I can not get to any local terminal with

```
ctrl-alt-f1
ctrl-alt-fn
```

However everything seems fine! I can ssh in, all my file systems are mounted correctly (ext4, xfs, cifs), all my data seems fine and there is no hint of problems in the logs. So where's my local terminal? It is quite disruptive to reboot again as it's a multi-user system and I already told the hoards they can log in after the reboot. Any advice on how to get a local terminal with rebooting much appreciated.

Thanks

S

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the problem. apache2 is configured with ssl keys which require a password. There is no way of entering a password on the local terminal (as there isn't one presented to the user) so I had to kill the httpd process over ssh and restart it, entering the password. This unfroze the boot screen on the local system allowing boot to complete properly. This seems to be an oversight/bug.

How to get around this? Maybe passing nosplash to grub? Don't allow httpd start at boot time? I'm not sure as I'm not going to reboot just to find out! If I hadn't had ssh(d) configured, or it was set to start after httpd then I would be stuck with an unresponsive system which would require a hard reset. Suboptimal.

S